# Woocommerce how to change selected variation when changing gallery thumbnails

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

By default Woocommerce changes the featured image on the gallery when you change the selected variation form the dropdown on variable products.

I want to vice versa that: when you swipe the product gallery thumbnails and the feature image changes i want to change the selected corresponding value on the dropdown.

Anyone?

Comment: Have you found the solution?